# Fill a list with objects depending on eachothers attributes

Tags: c#, list, loops

I have a List where I want to use the latest object created in the List to calculate the next objects attributes. I'm not sure how to write the loop doing that. Can you help me with that?

```
public ActionResult ShowDetail(DateTime startdate, double PresentValue, double InterestRate, double FutureValue, int PaymentPeriods)
    {
        List<Calculation> cList = new List<Calculation>();
        Calculation calc = new Calculation();
        calc.Date = startdate.ToShortDateString();
        calc.InvoiceAmount = 2000;
        calc.InterestRate = InterestRate;
        calc.InterestAmount = (PresentValue * InterestRate / 360 * 30);
        calc.Amortization = (2000 - (PresentValue * InterestRate / 360 * 30));
        calc.PresentValue = PresentValue;
        cList.Add(calc);
        for (int i = 0; i < PaymentPeriods; i++)
        {
            cList.Add(new Calculation()
                {
                    var calcBefore = cList.GetLastObject //Some how I want to take the object before the one i want to create
                    cList.Add(new Calculation()
                    {
                        Date = calcBefore.Date.Add(1).Month() //something like this
                        InvoiceAmount = calcBefore.InvoiceAmount
                        InterestRate = calcBefore.InterestRate
                        InterestAmount = (calcBefore.PresentValue * InterestRate / 360 * 30) //I want to take the presentvalue from the object before in the List and use that to calculate the the next InterestAmount
                        //And so on
                    }
                });
        }

        return PartialView("ShowDetail", cList);
    }
```

Calculation:

```
public partial class Calculation
{
   public string Date { get; set; }
   public double InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
   public double InterestRate { get; set; }
   public double InterestAmount { get; set; }
   public double Amortization { get; set; }
   public double PresentValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "I'm not sure how to write the loop doing that." ? Will edit the text so you can easier se it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the index of the list to access the last inserted:

```
var calcBefore = cList[cList.Count - 1];
```

another way which does the same: `Enumerable.Last`:

```
var calcBefore = cList.Last();
```

Since you have added one before the loop the list is not empty and this is safe.

Here is the complete loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PaymentPeriods; i++)
{
    calc = new Calculation();
    Calculation calcBefore = cList[cList.Count - 1];
    calc.Date = DateTime.Parse(calcBefore.Date).AddMonths(1).ToString();
    calc.InvoiceAmount = calcBefore.InvoiceAmount;
    calc.InterestRate = calcBefore.InterestRate;
    calc.InterestAmount = (calcBefore.PresentValue * InterestRate / 360 * 30);//I want to take the presentvalue from the object before in the List and use that to calculate the the next InterestAmount
    cList.Add(calc);
}
```

According to the `Date`, i assume you want to add one month, use `DateTime.AddMonths`:

```
Date = DateTime.Parse(calcBefore.Date).AddMonths(1).ToString();
```

However, i wouldn't use a `String` for a `DateTime` at all.

Comment: The String was just for testing but will change it now :) will test your code as well

Answer (score 0):

do not think you would use a loop,

All you would have to do is have a constructor take an Calculation object as a parameter.

Then you would do something like

```
public partial class Calculation
{
   public string Date { get; set; }
   public double InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
   public double InterestRate { get; set; }
   public double InterestAmount { get; set; }
   public double Amortization { get; set; }
   public double PresentValue { get; set; }

public   Calculation (Calculation as calculation(
   {
    ..  set you prop
   }
}
```

then when you call a new object, you pass in the last object in the current list

var newObj = new Calculation(cList[cList.Length -1]);